# Changing UISlider value by UISwipeGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I a trying to change slider value trough `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` , but it seems my code doesn't work ! I am using this code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];


    recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    recognizer.delegate = self;

}


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
    if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
        // prevent recognizing touches on the slider
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}



- (void) didSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    if([recognizer direction] == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft){

        NSLog(@"left");

         _label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",_slider.value];

        }else{

         NSLog(@"right");
    }
}
```

it just change the value to 0.0 it's like sliding something !

Comment: You can't use a single recognizer for both directions.

Comment: Why are you using a gesture recognizer to "change the slider" instead of letting the slider do it for you?

Answer (score 0):

In your didSwipe: method you just display value you don't try to change it. Replace your code with something like that:

```
- (void) didSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{
    if([recognizer direction] == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft){

        NSLog(@"left");

         _label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",_slider.value];
         // TODO: make sure that the value is not less than min slider value
         _slider.value = _slider.value - 5;

        }else{
         // TODO: make sure that the value is not larger than max slider value
         _slider.value = _slider.value + 5;
         NSLog(@"right");
    }
}
```

Also for optimalization you can replace your two gesture recognizer with just one:

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipe:)];
    [recognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft)];
    recognizer.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

Comment: nothing change ! does not feel you sliding ! just change a value

Comment: @Mc.Lover you said that you cannot change slider value with swipe gesture recognizer and the code above let you do that. Now you said that you want to change this value with smooth 'slide' animation. You cannot do this with Swipe gesture recognizer because you can get the location fromm swipe just once when the swipe ended. You should have a look on Pan gesure recognizer instead.